# Is it possible to shatter stone by dropping it into water from a significant height?

Tags: water, collision, material-science, estimation

If you had a stone approximately 1 meter in height, 1.5 meters in length, and .75 meters in width, could you drop it from a height into a body of water and shatter, significantly crack, or otherwise compromise the structural integrity of the stone? If so, what is the minimum height required to do so?

**Edit**
Also what if the material wasn't "stone" per se, but something less dense like concrete?

Comment: With enough kinetic energy, you can do a lot of damage to anything. That is the idea behind [this](https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2023/1/24/testing-the-us-militarys-worst-idea)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly why I'd like to know from what height it could be accomplished. I myself am a great fan of science, but never had the maths for it, thus I went into writing. I would absolutely not be able to live with myself if something I had written was plainly scientifically inaccurate.

Comment: Without doing any calculations, I think it is possible. Meteors even fracture when impacting air.